# Object.assign query

Tags: javascript

```js
let user = { name: "Nasir", age: 25 };
let employee = Object.assign( {}, user, { add: "dhaka", age: 35 } );

console.log( user ); //{ name: 'Nasir', age: 25 }
console.log( employee ); // { name: 'Nasir', age: 35, add: 'dhaka' }

//------------------------------------------//

let user1 = { name: "ahmed" };
let employee1 = Object.assign( user1, { permission: "can edit" } );

console.log( user1 ); // { name: 'ahmed', permission: 'can edit' }
console.log( employee1 ); //{ name: 'ahmed', permission: 'can edit' }
```

**Why `user1` object gets the property: `permission`?**

I copied `user1` objects properties to `employee1` and add additional property `permission`, so `permission` should be found
on only the `employee1` object, not in `user1`.

Please guide me, what did I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since, the `Object.assign()` has syntax `Object.assign(target, source)` so you are using `user1` as a target. Thus, use an empty object `{}` as a target so that the objects are merged in that target and the `user1` object is not changed.

```js
let user1 = {
  name: "ahmed"
};
let employee1 = Object.assign({}, user1, {
  permission: "can edit"
});
console.log(user1); // { name: 'ahmed' }
console.log(employee1); //{ name: 'ahmed', permission: 'can edit' }
```

You can even use the spread syntax to achieve this:

```js
let user1 = {
  name: "ahmed"
};
let employee1 = {
  ...user1,
  ...{ permission: "can edit" }
}
console.log(user1); // { name: 'ahmed' }
console.log(employee1); //{ name: 'ahmed', permission: 'can edit' }
```

Comment: `console.log(user1); // { name: 'ahmed'}` only.

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong thanks for the suggestion

Comment: So the summary is, if I omit first parameter in `Object.assign()` method, the `source` argument will be act like `target` argument. Is it correct ?

Comment: No, in that case, the target is not used. As a result, you just store the result into `employee1` Then use it. Check [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67069845/9071943) in more detail If you want. @Nasir

Comment: i got this issue. but my question is, as per you say, the target is not used. As a result, you just store the result into `employee1` Then use it. Then why user1 object gets the `permission` property as far i add this property to employee1?

Comment: No, your code is `Object.assign(user1`, it should be `Object.assign({}, user1`. I've just updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67069845/9071943) to point out the difference between target and source object. Hopefully, this was useful to you @Nasir

Answer (score 3):

According to [MDN's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) docs says that

> Properties in the *`target object are overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key`*. Later sources' properties overwrite
> earlier ones

And, the syntax is

```
Object.assign(target, ...sources)
```

So that's the reason why `user1` has been changed.

---

**Solution,** *There are 2 options:*

1. Create a dummy `target` object by adding `{}` at first param.

Please take a closer the second param `...sources`, and specs say that

> The Object.assign() method copies all enumerable own properties from
> **one or more source** objects to a target object

so from the second params that act as `source`.

```js
let user1 = { name: "ahmed" };
let employee1 = Object.assign({}, user1, { permission: "can edit" } );

console.log(user1); // { name: 'ahmed' }
console.log(employee1); //{ name: 'ahmed', permission: 'can edit' }
```

2. Using [Spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)

```js
let user1 = { name: "ahmed" };
let employee1 = {...user1, ...{permission: 'can edit'}}

console.log(user1); // { name: 'ahmed' }
console.log(employee1); //{ name: 'ahmed', permission: 'can edit' }
```

Comment: Thank you very much..now Object.assign() is clear to me as rain

Comment: I've just updated my answer to point out the difference between `target` and `source` object. Hopefully, this was useful to you @Nasir

Answer (score 2):

```
let user1 = { name: "ahmed" };
let employee1 = {...user1,...{ permission: "can edit" }};
console.log( user1 ); // { name: 'ahmed', permission: 'can edit' }
console.log( employee1 );
```

`Object.assign(obj1,obj2 ,....)`  Here assign method will add all property or object to left side object or the object you have in first Param (i.e obj1) that is why its return in both.
so try `{}` in first left side or use above shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that `Object.assign()` alters the first parameter object given to it. In the first care you are altering an empty object `{}` and in the second case you are altering `user1` object.